# Moving files via batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to move files to directories that has the same name as the file, excluding the extension and add the word `footage` to the end of the directory name:

For example:

File `Graduation 2014.mkv` should be moved to folder `Graduation 2014 Footage`
File `Graduation 2015.mkv` should be moved to folder `Graduation 2015 Footage`
etc.

Here is what I have tried:

```
@echo off
 for %%A in (*.mkv) do (
   move "%%A" "%%~nA:~0,-8"
 )
 pause`
```

bu I get the following error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.*

Comment: There is no `.` between filename and extension. `*.mkv`.

Comment: @PunyTed Do you need to make these folders or do they already exist?

Comment: I am a bit unclear on the folder name? so the folder will be called `File_mkv`?

Comment: that is even more unclear. the first half is the same as the folder? Please show me an actual example, not filexxx

Comment: Much better.. once question, can there be more than one name? i.e `Graduation 2014` and `Graduation 2016`?

Comment: hmmmm. ok, so we then assume a file will always be 3 word sentence?

Comment: @PunyTed, when you're finished, deciding what the task is, can you let us know, I do not want to have to create answers then delete them again due to significant changes in your requirements.

Comment: As it stands your folders do not have the same name except for the last 4 characters, but your question states that they do. In fact, in the present edit of your question, the pattern appears to be that you want to move every file into a directory holding the same basename but suffixed with a space character followed by the string `footage`. Is this the case?

Comment: ok, I suggest you review your entire question and give proper explanations as you refer to last 4 characters, which is nowehere to be seen in examples. Show all the possibilities please so we are clear on what is going on here.

Comment: nope, still not correct. You say 8 same name, besides the last 8 characters, but it is not the same, the file starts with `moving` and your folder does not have it.

Comment: still not very clear, what you really want. As your question stands right now, replacing `move "%%A" "%%~nA:~0,-8"` with  `move "%%A" "%%~nA Footage\"` should do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple solution works for me.

**Here is the Folder Names as Example:**

```
File1_ext
12345_5678
43226343_12
224356434
File2_ext
File3_ext
Folder_exc
File4_ext
Ect-Hello
```

**Output Tree:**

```
C:.
│   Move.bat
│
├───12345_5678
├───224356434
├───43226343_12
├───Ect-Hello
├───File1_ext
│       File1.mkv
│
├───File2_ext
│       File2.mkv
│
├───File3_ext
│       File3.mkv
│
├───File4_ext
│       File4.mkv
│
└───Folder_exc
```

**Batch Script:**

```
@echo off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Rem | Get File Name
FOR %%A IN (*.mkv) do (
    Set "FileExt=%%~xA"
    Set "FileName=%%~nA"

    Rem | Get Folder Name
    for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('dir /b /a:d^| find /i "!FileName!"') do (

        Move "!FileName!!FileExt!" "%~dp0%%B"
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: This is what I read from the post. He keeps editing it and y'all have to baby feed him for results. Sorry if this was the solution from 30 mins ago and if I missed it.

Comment: @JohnKens Sorry, about that re editting the post repeated I was told that the information I provided was not enough or specific. But you solution worked fine for me. Thank you.

Comment: @PunyTed I am honestly confused by what you really wanted.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I'm sorry my initial phrasing might have left too much up to interpretation. Thanks for the effort you put in. Apologies for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer only based purely this line in your question.

> Trying to move files(.mkv) into folders that have the same name except for the last 8 characters.

I believe you should have simply just did this and let the script create the folder for you:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.mkv) do (
   mkdir "%%~ni Footage">nul 2>&1
   move "%%i"  "%%~ni Footage"
)
pause
```

or if you insist on not making the script create the folder, simply do:

```
@for %%i in (*.mkv) do @move "%%i"  "%%~ni Footage"
```

Comment: ok, but I explained to you that it would be much easier to let the script do the folder creation, based on the name, simply because you will get issues when this is the case. if you had two mkv files, `summer graduation 2014.mkv` and `summer graduation 2014 New York.mkv` then john's answer will not work because it will find two matching folders. Also, your examples made no sense because they had an additional word in the beginning which was not catered for at all? Anyway, This was simply to explain to you that you should be clear on your questions to make it easier for us.

Comment: The folders were already made and contained other stuff like subtitle files. If making new empty folders with the same name merges them together (I'm not sure) then you are right. However your script seem to put all the .mkv files into the first folder that ends with footage instead of separating them by the prefixes. Yes, its true that john's answer will not be effective then, but my files that are going into the same folder do not have a different sulfix at the end so its fine.

Comment: If the addition word you are referring to is 'Moving' that is the action I want to take, its not part of the .mkv name and so I did not bold it. Once again I'm sorry for any frustration this have caused you.

Comment: Yes, but the word was highlighted as such, I have fixed your question, so hopefully you'll better post the next one :)

Comment: @PunyTed oh and fixed the script, forgot to remove the `/f` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it in a *slightly* different way than others. Gerhard Barnard and John Kens suggested to make a simple `for` loop through all `*.mkv` files. However, this won't work if there are hidden files. You may have an alternative extremely general solution:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b /a-d "C:\some\path\to\mkvs" *.mkv') do (
    attrib -h "%%~fA" >nul 2>&1
    if not exist "%%~dpnA Footage\" md "%%~dpnA"
    move "%%~fA" "%%~dpnA Footage\"
)
```

which is surely more secure since we are using full paths. The `if exist` may be pointless here because you can do:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b /a-d "C:\some\path\to\mkvs" *.mkv') do (
    attrib -h "%%~fA" >nul 2>&1
    md "%%~dpnA" >nul 2>&1
    move "%%~fA" "%%~dpnA Footage\"
)
```

which means to redirect any output (errors and STDOUT) to `nul`, so hide them.